# Chart (or picture) does't appear in Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have been using visual studio 2013 along with crystal report service pack 9.
I also have created a window form to make a report with chart. The data works fine, but the chart or even picture doesn't appear in the report (only text data).

can anyone tell me where my problem is ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to change different crystal report file , please make sure that you edit and run the same file